# Animations not working in the BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a simple character (below) that is in the middle of an animation that does not work with my logic bricks.

[image: Character in middle of animation]

Here are my logic bricks. Sorry, may be hard to read (click on the image for a bigger version).

[image: Logic Bricks]

It states that when the property *inMovement* is set to 1, it will play a walk animation, and, on the other hand, it will not when it is set to 0. I thought that the problem would be with the parenting, but it all looked fine:

[image: Outliner]

After this I thought that the animation just didn't work, but it did. This is the animation of my blocky character picture at top.

[image: Animations].

Everything I stated here is true, and I did not lie and/or take pictures at different times. All the screenshots were taken at one point in time, and no editing was done between them.

How do I get the animations to play (*Loop Stop*) based on whether the value is set to 1 or 0?

Comment: Could you post a .blend file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently making a game myself, and what i do is connect the *W A S D keyboard sensors* to individual *AND controllers*. These each go to seperate *MOTION actuators* directing the speed and direction to walk in (A and D can be set to rotation). Then create an *ACTION actuator* with your animation in it and connect it up to the *AND controllers* of the *W A S D sensors*. You can reverse the animation for *S key* by duplicating the *ACTION actuator* and reversing the *KEYFRAMES*. If *A and D* are for rotating, don't add the action.

Comment: Thanks! That is an answer, but I already had it solved.